# Что означает "крайней необходимости" в тексте при попытке править вопрос анонимным пользователем?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предлагаемые-правки, анонимный-пользователь

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что в этом тексте означает "крайняя необходимость"? Да и не совсем ясно, что значит "существенные". У нас тут споры на эту тему между старыми пользователями возникают, а новичок совсем не в теме.

Может туда добавим какую-нибудь ссылку с пояснениями?

Comment: Проще всего удалить 2-й абзац, тогда и пояснять ничего не придется

Comment: Пояснять все равно надо...

Answer (score 9):

Да, эта надпись некорректна и только вводит в заблуждение. Если в какой-то правке имеется "крайняя необходимость", она не может быть несущественной. Из этого текста можно понять, что от редакторов ожидается добавление значительных кусков текста через механизм предложенных правок, а косметические исправления наоборот, не приветствуются, что не соответствует действительности. Если на то пошло, скорее наоборот, внесение *существенных* правок должно быть обусловлено крайней необходимостью.

Однако, эта надпись в нашем интерфейсе является правильным переводом надписи из англоязычного интерфейса:

> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary.

Изменение ее на что-то другое будет восприниматься как локализаторский произвол. Необходимо обсуждение на MSE, чтобы сначала изменить исходную надпись.

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

В вопросе есть сообщение об ошибке, часть которого интерпретируется, как markdown разметка, что приводит к некорректному отображению.

Исправить вопрос, чтобы он отображался нормально - абсолютно необходимо, даже если правка будет заключаться в добавлении или удалении одного символа.

Данное предупреждение ориентировано в первую очередь на тех любителей кармы, которые находят себе "золотую жилу" в виде одной какой-нибудь опечатки, и начинают исправлять её во всех ответах подряд. Или делать еще какие-нибудь мелкие правки, типа заглавных букв. Не чтобы улучшить восприятие вопроса, а просто потому что им заняться больше нечем.

Comment: То есть вы считаете, что исправление грамматических и орфографических ошибок в вопросах и ответах не является их улучшением и лучше этим не заниматься? А как относитесь к информационному шуму вроде "Привет всем форумчанам" и т.п.?